# prevent scraping of web content in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, web-scraping

I'm working on a site containing real estate listings in Spring MVC.  I would like to prevent scripts to steal the content by scraping the site.  Does anyone have experience with techniques that can easily be plugged in to a spring mvc environment?

User-agent is too simple to circumvent.

One idea I had was to keep track of two counters on the serverside.
ipaddress --> (counter xhr request, counter page request)

- the counter page request is increased with a filter
- the counter xhr request is increased on document ready

If a filter notices the two counters are totally out of sync, the ip is blocked.

Could this work or are there easier techniques?

Cheers

**edit**

I am aware that if scrapers are persistent they will find a way to get the content.  However, I'd like to make it as hard as possible.

Comment: If you are concerned about search engines then look at robots.txt heres a tutorial http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/ and heres googles implementation http://www.google.com/robots.txt

Comment: You can spend a lot of time on this or realize that if someone wants to scrape your site badly enough THEY WILL and there's really nothing you can do about it.  If you publish information to a freely and anonymously accessible medium you cannot really expect to protect it

Comment: Login with Captcha... and say goodbye to browsing visitors.

Comment: ... and say goodbye to 1/googlebot and 2/regular users?  no thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

- Look for patterns in how your pages are requested.  Regular intervals is a flag.  Regular frequency might be a flag (four times a day, but at different times during the day).
- Require login.  Nothing gets shown until the user logs in, so at least the scraper has to have an account.
- Mix up the tag names around the content every once in a while.  It might break their script.  Do this enough times and they'll search for greener pastures.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop it at all, but you can make it harder as much as possible.

One way to make it harder is change your content URL very frequent base on time with appending some encrypted flag in url.

Some of suggestion are in given link.
http://blog.screen-scraper.com/2009/08/17/further-thoughts-on-hindering-screen-scraping/ 
http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-blog-content-scraping-how-to-stop-it/

Answer (score 0):

Load the content via ajax.
Make the ajax request dynamic so they cant just go and scrape the ajax request.

Only sophisticated scrapers support execution of java script.

Most scrapers dont run the pages through a real browser, so you can try to use that to your advantage.